# Windows XP service not sending parameters to .net app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I have created a Windowx XP service and pointed it to an executable of a C# application.

After right-clicking the service and selecting Properties, I entered an argument in the "start parameters" box, but in the first line of the C# application `args[]` doesn't contain anything.

How do I pass the arguments to the application when it is being executed as a service?

Comment: This was through the Service's Properties box?

Comment: Hi, it is a plain application called from the service I created within windows?

Comment: There is? http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sys_srv_start_service.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: You're right, well I didn't know!